# PHP Notice: Undefined variable: usuario2

Tags: php

Estoy aprendiendo a utilizar PHP y pude solucionar algunos errores gracias a ésta web.
Espero que alguien con más experiencia pueda ayudarme con el problema. Será problema de alguna extensión, anteriormente funcionaba bien en PHP5 y al cambiar de hosting con PHP7 parece que hay algunas extensiones que quedaron obsoletas y no funcionan en esta versión.
Me muestra el siguiente error:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: usuario2 in /home/admin/web/websitepublic_html/principal.php on line 46

La línea 46 es la siguiente:

> $sql="select * from as1g_c0d where email='$usuario2'";

```
<?php
require_once("sesion.class.php");

$sesion = new sesion();
$usuario = $sesion->get("l0g1n");

if( $usuario == false ){    
    header("Location: index.php");      
}
else 
{
?>

<?php

include("conexion.php");

$consulta1="select * from l0g1n where email='$usuario'";
$resul1=mysqli_query($conex, $consulta1) or die(mysqli_error());
$cont1=mysqli_num_rows($resul1);

if($cont1==0){ 


}
else
{
$consulta2= mysqli_query("SELECT dni FROM l0g1n where email='$usuario'");
    if ($resul2 = mysqli_fetch_row($consulta2)) 
    {
    $usu2 = trim($resul2[0]);

    $consulta3= mysqli_query("SELECT email FROM as1g_c0d where dni='$usu2'");
        if ($resul3 = mysqli_fetch_row($consulta3)) 
        {
        $usuario2 = trim($resul3[0]);
        }
    }
}
?>

<?php

include("conexion.php");

$sql="select * from as1g_c0d where email='$usuario2'";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conex, $sql) or die (mysqli_error());
$fila=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

if($fila==0){ 


}
else
{
$query= mysqli_query("SELECT nombres FROM as1g_c0d where email='$usuario2'");
    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query)) 
    {
    $id = trim($row[0]);

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Una pregunta, si todos los campos que necesitas los tienes en la tabla `as1g_c0d`, ¿Por que no traerlos en una sola consulta?

Answer (score 1):

Te comento que en tu codigo pareciera que tienes dos archivos diferentes (ya que abres y cierras `<?php ?>` dos veces), sin embargo voy a tomar como que es uno y te voy a explicar el error logico que presenta tu codigo.

El error te dice que no hay ninguna variable seteada con el nombre `$usuario2` y de hecho tiene mucho sentido, ya que la unica aparicion de esa variable es dentro de una condicional

```
 if ($resul3 = mysqli_fetch_row($consulta3)) 
 {
     $usuario2 = trim($resul3[0]);
 }
```

Lo cual significa que si tu consulta 3 no sale de forma esperada entonces nunca vas a haber setado tu variable `$usuario2`, te recomiendo que reacomodes la logica de tu codigo ya que tienes varios puntos inalcanzables para ciertas variables ya que estan seteadas dentro de condiciones, lo que puedes hacer para corregir este error es setear desde antes la variable `$usuario2=NULL;` con esto ya no te generara ese error aunque si la condicion antes mencionada sale como falsa entonces

```
$sql="select * from as1g_c0d where email='$usuario2'";
```

quedaria como nula.

Espero haberte ayudado.

## Edicion

Con el siguiente codigo se puede evitar el error

```
$consulta2= mysqli_query("SELECT dni FROM l0g1n where email='$usuario'");
$resul2 = mysqli_fetch_row($consulta2); 

$usu2 = trim($resul2[0]);

$consulta3= mysqli_query("SELECT email FROM as1g_c0d where dni='$usu2'");
    
$usuario2 = trim($resul3[0]);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero necesito que muestre un valor y no quede nula.

Comment: En ese caso tienes ciertos errores de secuencia, modifique el codigo, con eso evitas el error, sin embargo te recomiendo que revises tu secuencializacion y ademas apliques queries preparadas

Answer (score 0):

recuerda que según la semántica de php su lectura es línea por línea, entonces cuando llega a $usuario2, solo la estás ocupando ahí y no está declarada.

Te recomiendo que siempre inicialices tus variables en el principio del archivo, si tienes idea de guardar información y ocuparla más abajo; Como es en tu caso.

```
/** inicializando variables **/
 $usu2 = null; 
 $usuario2 = null;
 $id = null;
```

Espero que te ayude un poco.

Comment: Gracias por responder, logré ubicar el error.